# Failed to translate JSON to XML. cannot normalize -- empty value

Tags: xml, xsd, oracle-data-integrator

I get error in ODI 12c where I use Complex Filex = json and create from it XSD and I want test it:

```
Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: class java.sql.SQLException
oracle.odi.jdbc.driver.xml.io.exception.PipelineStageException: ORABPEL-15235

Translation Failure.
Failed to translate JSON to XML. cannot normalize!
The incoming data does not conform to the NXSD schema. Please correct the problem.
```

I get this error when xml has "" value for example:
"lastName":""

When I change value for null or any string it is working fine. ("lastName":null or "lastName":"test")

What can I do?

In XSD file I have information like:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/InboundService" targetNamespace="http://TargetNamespace.com/InboundService" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd" nxsd:version="JSON" nxsd:encoding="UTF-8">
```

Maybe I must add something?

Code for last name: <xsd:element name="lastName" type="xsd:string"/>

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am stuck on this as well.